# How to stop a "screen taking" command in bash script and not the script itself?

Tags: bash, shell

When I am running the htop command in a bash script the only way to exit it is to `CTRL+C` but it close the script.
Is there a solution to only stop the running command but not the script ?

Comment: You can exit htop without ctrl+c, by typing `q`.

Comment: I can't reproduce! As @CharlesDuffy said: `q` key still quit `htop` even if run through a bash script!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the linux `trap` command with **SIGINT** signal for `CTRL+C`.

This can be used to invoke the set of commands that needs to run after interrupting the `htop`

```
trap on_htop_exit SIGINT

on_htop_exit() {
   echo "htop interrupted"
   # remainder of the script 
}

htop
```

Refer: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/trap.1p.html

Comment: Note that TLDP is not well-regarded as a reference source -- the [Wooledge BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) was written specifically to divert people from their "Advanced" Bash Scripting guide, because the #bash IRC channel was spending too much of our time trying to get people to unlearn bad habits they picked up from TLDP-written sources.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy, I was not aware of that.